Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + (a+b+c)^2 \leq 4$. Prove that
Let $a, b, c$ be positive real numbers such that $a^2 + b^2 + c^2 + (a+b+c)^2 \leq 4$. Prove that $\frac{ab+1}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{cb+1}{(c+b)^2}+\frac{ac+1}{(a+c)^2} \leq 3$.
I tried the given question. It was on my test.
I realized that the above inequality can be written as $(a+b)^2 + (b+c)^2 + (c+a)^2 \leq 4$. I tried to apply AM-GM-HM inequality and Titu's lemma, they didn't seem to work. What shall I do now?

Not sure if this helps, but one might notice
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+(a+b+c)^2 = 2(a^2+b^2+c^2+ab+bc+ca) = (a+b)^2+(b+c)^2+(c+a)^2$$

This question is similar to: Prove this Complicated Inequality. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Approach0 search ...

(cont.) was used to find this. Note that I've seen about $10$ posts, both on this site and AoPS, where the second inequality's RHS is $\ge 3$ rather than $\le 3$. As such, I assume that's the case and you have a typo. Also, as I just mentioned, there are many other duplicates. For example, on this site, there's USA $2011$ contest inequality problem, proving $\frac{ab+1}{(a+b)^2}+\frac{bc+1}{(b+c)^2}+\frac{ca+1}{(c+a)^2}\ge 3$, under given condition., as well as the AoPS threads Inequality from USAMO, ...

(cont.) inequality, Inequality problem!, a^2+b^2+c^2+...<=4: 2011 USAMO #1, 2011 USAJMO #2, SOLVE-3 tasks (where your problem is the third task), etc. Finally, welcome to Math SE.

Oh, yes, it Is a typo sorry.
